# Grassmannian $G(2,3)$ homeomorphic to the projective plane $\mathbb{P}_{\mathbb{R}}^2$

Tags: proof-writing, projective-space, grassmannian

I'm studying the Grassmannian for low dimensions and I saw that $G(2,3)\cong \mathbb{P}_{\mathbb{R}}^2$.

Reference: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grassmannian

Mostly, I understand the intuitive idea, but I don't know how to formalize that this is true. Could anyone give a rigorous proof of that or recommend me what way should I take?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The general statement is that $G(k,n)$ is homeomorphic to $G(n-k, n)$ for any $0\leq k\leq n$.

One particularly natural homeomorphism $f:G(k,n)\rightarrow G(n-k,n)$ is given as follows.  A point $p\in G(k,n)$ is really a $k$-dimensional subspace of $\mathbb{R}^n$.  Using the canonical inner product on $\mathbb{R}^n$, there is an orthogonal complement $q$ to $p$.  This is an $n-k$ dimensional subspace with $p\oplus q = \mathbb{R}^n$.

Then map $f$ sends $p$ to $q$.  The inverse map works the same way.

Applied to your situation, this just says that $G(2,3)\cong G(1,3)$.  But, simply note that $G(1,n)$ is the set of $1$-d subspaces in $\mathbb{R}^n$.  That is, is the set of all lines though the origin in $\mathbb{R}^n$.  So $G(1,n) = \mathbb{P}^{n-1}_\mathbb{R}.$

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it was brilliant! I have a doubt at the end. Why is $G(1,n)=\mathbb{P}_{\mathbb{R}}^n$? I think that $G(1,n)=\mathbb{P}_{\mathbb{R}}^{n-1}$. See, for instance, the example of Low Dimensions I referenced before

Comment: @mishu:  You're right: it should be $\mathbb{P}^{n-1}_\mathbb{R}$.  Fixing now...